# Laravel/lumen tymon/jwt-auth get data from JWT token providing first user record

Tags: laravel, jwt, lumen

```
 $token = $this->jwt->getToken();
 $this->jwt->user();
 $data = $this->jwt->setToken($token)->toUser();
```

I am trying to get the user detail based on token in laravel/Lumen but its always return the first user details. I already cross check the login detail which is fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `JWTAuth::toUser($token)`?

Comment: same issue with this also

Comment: Check if your token is not null...

Comment: already check. token is not null

Comment: What is the 'id' field that JWTAuth uses? check the jwtauth config file

Comment: thank you for support. i got the issue . actually auto increment is not false in my model... not its working fine  :)